# Toggle LED with button

Tags: button, embedded, led, microchip

Since this is my first post, please have patience with me :)

I am developing code for a program that outputs a signal high or low.

First my first test, I have successfully made an LED flash on if button pressed and LED flash off when released.

For my second test, I am trying to make it to that I can TOGGLE the LED on or off when I press the button once. If I press the button LED remains on and if I pressed the button, LED remains off. Is that clear?

The button is active low and idle high.

This is the code so far:

```
If TOUCH_0 = 0 Then
    If LED_1 = 0 And TOUCH_0 = 1 Then
    High LED_1
  EndIf
EndIf                 

If TOUCH_0 = 1 Then
  If LED_1 = 1 And TOUCH_0 = 0 Then
    Low LED_1
  EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: If button is pressed then toggle LED. I hope this is what you need.code should look like : if(button pressed) { LED_PIN ^= 0X01;//xor operation }

Comment: It is probably wrong to first check `TOUCH_0` for 0 or 1 and then inside the IF block again for the opposite value, 1 and 0 resp. Which programming language is this? You might need to debounce the button, too.

Comment: You need to learn about switch debouncing: in simple terms, if you see that the state has changed, you should then *ignore* the switch for some fraction of a second.